# What is the probability for each number in a set of random numbers to be the highest number in the set?

Tags: probability

I have viewed/researched many problems on this website but this is my first question.  I'm a little apprehensive by the length of the question but I have tried to explain it fully including a little of my thought process.  The problem is ...

I have n numbers in a set (N1, N2, N3 ... Nn). For each number I choose a random number (R1, R2, R3 ... Rn) between 1 and the number (e.g. 0 < R1 < N1, 0 < R2 < N2, 0 < R3 < N3 ... 0 < Rn < Nn ).  My quest is to seek the probability for each random number that it should be the largest of the random numbers in the set i.e. P(R1=max(R1 ... Rn)), P(R2=max(R1 ... Rn)) etc. up to P(Rn=max(R1 ... Rn)).

For example and by way of a Monte Carlo simulation (MCS) with a count of 10,000 I get the following ...

N1=300, N2=250, N3=450

R1 is Max(R1,R2,R3) 2576 times i.e. P(R1=Max(R1,R2,R3)) = 0.2576

R2 is Max(R1,R2,R3) 1526 times i.e. P(R2=Max(R1,R2,R3)) = 0.1526

R3 is Max(R1,R2,R3) 5898 times i.e. P(R3=Max(R1,R2,R3)) = 0.5898

Obviously the MCS will produce a slightly different result each time it is run. On 10 runs the MCS returned results of ...

```
  N1   N2  N3
```

Min 2504 1499 5854

Ave 2546 1534 5921

Max 2591 1564 5972

Interestingly using some Mathematica code as provided by the Wolfram forum the probabilities were calculated as ...

P(R1=Max(R1,R2,R3))= 0.256173

P(R2=Max(R1,R2,R3))= 0.154321

P(R3=Max(R1,R2,R3))= 0.589506

So it seems there is probably a formula to return the expected result from an infinite number of MCS runs but it's proving difficult to find it!

A helpful Wolfram forumite from another time zone promised to help me after a good night's sleep but unfortunately they deleted my thread before he woke up because I was not seeking Mathematica support!  :(

Anyway if someone could help with a formula or point to where I may find one I would be very grateful.  I need to be able to resolve this using Excel, SQL or VBA because the result needs to link with an existing SQL database so the MCS option is not really suitable.  That was only for testing and is not a viable option because I have c.150,000 number sets with 75% of them having between 5 and 12 numbers to each set and the thought of performing that number of MCS's throws my computer into a cold sweat! :)

Well if you have got this far thank you for reading my question ... it is long but hopefully most of the content is for explanation and not question.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Interesting problem.  If the query had not already been upvoted to 3, I would have upvoted it.

Answer (score 1):

Assume we are interested in the probability that the number $R_m$ is the largest one.

The probability of this is:
$$
P(R_m)=\frac1{N_m}\sum_{i=1}^{N_m}\prod_{k\ne m}\frac{\min(i,N_k)}{N_k}.\tag1$$

Particularly for your example one obtais:
$$P_1=0.257285,\ P_2=0.590619,\ P_3=0.155248.$$

This differs slightly from your result and besides does not sum to $1$. The reason for this is the fact that the result of a trial is ambiguous if there are two or more largerst numbers, so that the events "$R_1$ is the largest number" and "$R_2$ is the largest number" do not exclude each other if $R_1=R_2$.

Actually it is very strange that you did not report about such cases, because the probability of an event with multiple "winners" in your example is $0.0031$ and one would expect about 31 such events in 10000 trials. In your statistics however they are not present. I suspect you either discard such trials or somehow assign the largest property to one of the "winners".

---

**UPDATE for real random numbers.**

In the case of real random numbers the equation (1) turns into:
$$
P(R_m)=\frac1{N_m}\int_0^{N_m}\prod_{k\ne m}\frac{\min(x,N_k)}{N_k}dx\tag2
$$

This expression can be simplified as follows. Let
$N_1\le N_2\le \dots\le N_n$. Then
$$\begin{align}
P(R_m)&=\frac1{\prod\limits_{k}N_k}
\Big[\int_0^{N_1}x^{n-1}dx+N_1\int_{N_1}^{N_2} x^{n-2}dx\\
&+N_1N_2\int_{N_2}^{N_3} x^{n-3}dx+\cdots+
N_1N_2\dots N_{m-1}\int_{N_{m-1}}^{N_m} x^{n-m}dx
\Big]\\
&=\frac{\prod_{k>m}\frac{N_m}{N_k}}{(n-m+1)}
-\sum_{i=1}^{m-1}\frac{\prod_{k>i}\frac{N_i}{N_k}}{(n-i+1)(n-i)}.
\tag3
\end{align}$$

Particularly in your example one obtains:
$$
P(R_2)=\frac{50}{324}\approx0.154321,\quad P(R_1)=\frac{83}{324}\approx0.256173,\quad P(R_3)=\frac{191}{324}\approx0.589506.
$$
in agreement with reported *Mathematica* result.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I accept the added complication where two or more calculated random numbers for a set are equal but confess the 'error' would be acceptable.  I will be comparing the inverse if the probability with another (external) number to select those values that fall outside the 'probability calculated value' by + or - 20% or more/less.  So in the instance of P2 the inverse of the two probabilities are 6.48 for Matematica and 6.44 for your formula, a varience of 0.54%, which would not significantly affect the 'decision' that will follow.

Comment: My problem is how to convert your formula into workable code in VBA!  I can easily create an accumulative for/next loop to calculate R1, R2 and R3 ... compare them to find the largest and increment a counter (C1, C2, C3) for the largest but I am expecting a formula to be more efficient bearing in mind the large number of calculations required.

Comment: Sorry I have given thought to your comment re ties.  The reason is I referred to the random numbers as Integers because I thought it would simplify the question but without considering the impact of ties caused by this.  My MCS runs were performed with non-integers and therefore did not have any ties.  My apologies and thanks for raising this ... I have edited the original post.

Comment: @ElpacRovi I have updated my answer to incorporate the continous case.

Comment: Again thank you again for your efforts @User to help me and my apologies if my ignorance of mathematical symbols and conventions cause me to ask for explanations!  You are using parameters "n", "m", "k" and "i".  I'm guessing "i" is simply a 'counter' for the $\sum$, yes?  I'm confused whether "n" or "m" (if either) relate to the number of values in a set of numbers.  I would have expected "n" to be this (as used by me) but I see you use "$P(R_m)$" so I'm not sure if you are using "m" as the values in a set parameter (if at all! :( ).

Comment: And whichever it is still leaves the other notation, and "k", undefined (in my mind).  I believe $\prod_\limits{k>m}$ means multiply numbers where "k>m", yes?  But I'm sorry to say I cannot find a substantial explanation of "${N_m^{n-m}}$" in my search!  The closest I can get is N(μ,σ2) referred to as a "gaussian distribution" which is something I have heard of but never studied.

Comment: @ElpacRovi $N_m^{n-m}=(N_m) ^{n-m}$. In words : "$(n-m)$-th power of $N_m$". $i$ and $k$ just mute indices.

Comment: @ElpacRovi I have rewritten the final expression in a form more suitable for calculation.

Comment: I have a hunch the second-to-last equation (with ${N_{i}^{n-i}}/{\prod_{k>i}N_k}$) is easier to program in VBA than the last one (with $\prod_k\min\left(1,\frac{N_i}{N_k}\right)$).

Comment: @DavidK You may be right. In any case the last expression is easier to understand (I guess). :)

Comment: Thanks again guys and sorry to be a persistent pain but, as mentioned in an earlier comment, I still have no idea of the definitions of "n", "m" and "k"!  Nor do I understand what is meant by "k just mute indices."  :(

Comment: @ElpacRovi Do you understand, what the symbols $\prod$ and $\sum$ and the small letters under the symbols mean?

Comment: @ElpacRovi Here are some explanations: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_binary_operation

Comment: @user, thank you for your continued patience.  I understand $\sum_x^y$ to mean sum the function for the variable from "x" to "y" inclusive.  And as I said before "I believe $\prod_\limits{k>m}$ means multiply the numbers where "k>m", yes?" but that doesn't define "m", "n" and "k".  I can assume you are using "n" as I did in the original post i.e. to notate the series of numbers but where did "m" and "k" come from?  They just appeared without definition. :(   And sorry for the $N_m^{n-m}$ confusion.  I saw it as N between the limits of "m" and "n−m" and not "(n−m)-th power of Nm"!   Sorry.

Comment: And thank you @user for the link to the Wiki page, I had already checked with that page and https://www.rapidtables.com/math/symbols/Basic_Math_Symbols.html ... my problem is not the meaning of the symbols but the definition of the variables you are referring to.

Comment: @ElpacRovi Because of your claim that I did not define $k$ I have serious doubts that you carefully read the section "Notation" in the link I gave in my previous comment. Would you understand if instead of "$k>m$" I write "$k\in\mathbb N, m<k\le n$"? And yes, I am using $n$ as you did it in the original post, namely to denote the amount of numbers in the set $N_1,N_2,\dots,N_n$. You should however keep in mind that I have sorted the numbers according to $N_i\le N_{i+1}$.

Comment: @user, I'm sorry but there is clearly no meeting of the minds as the Greeks would say.  I have re-read the section "Notation" in the en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_binary_operation page.  There is no mention of "k" in the Notation section, not even the prose!  Nor is there a definition of "m".  I'm sure your help is totally correct theory but theory is only of use if it can be actually calculated.  I made it clear in my OP that I sought a formula I could code with SQL or VBA.  That has not been forthcoming.  I cannot code a formula where some of the variables are not clearly defined.

Comment: So I think it's time to call it a day, before we both lose our patience.  This is not working for either party.  I am going to concentrate my efforts on Python or maybe the Mathematica language and use the known functions there and link then into the website.  It may take longer but it will be quicker in the long run!  I thank you for your attempts to help but we do not even seem to be able to read the same text.  All I am looking for is a practicle (a+b)*c^d type of formula but it seems this website only deals in theories without the how.  :(  Thank you for your generous efforts.

Comment: Did you read this: "Iterated binary operations are used to represent an operation that will be repeated over a set subject to some constraints. Typically the lower bound of a restriction is written under the symbol, and the upper bound over the symbol, though they may also be written as superscripts and subscripts in compact notation. Interpolation is performed over positive integers from the lower to upper bound, to produce the set which will be substituted into the index (below denoted as $i $) for the repeated operations." What does it mean for you?

Comment: All variables are clearly defined, and as you could note the formula is very practical and produces computational result identical to your simulations. It is not my fault that you cannot use them. I wish you a great success in your attempts.

Comment: @User, Yes I did read "Iterated binary operations are ..." and I understood it to mean "Iterated binary operations are ...".  I knew the notation of subscripting and superscripting limits in summation, integration etc. before coming here but I still cannot see a "k" nor an "m" anywhere in the Notation section!  Why do you keep claiming they are clearly defined when it's in black and white by omission they are not?  As I have said, a character of "k" does not even appear in the text of that section let alone the notations.  Please give me a direct line number and character number reference.

Comment: It's clear that we are just not reading the same page or I am misreading the correct page.  What else should I be looking for other than "k" and "m"?  I cannot agree something is clearly defined if I cannot see it.  And I'm sorry but it is your fault if you tell me to read and re-read something and it's not there.  That cannot fit the definition of "clearly defined".  "Insanity is doing the same thing over and over again, but expecting different results" but you keep insisting I go over the same article again and again and expect me to have a different result!  Do you disagree with Einstein?

Comment: @ElpacRovi Thank you very much that you found time to share with me your thoughts! Let us continue this interesting and exciting discussion when you have some new ideas about what the symbols $$\sum_ia_i,\text{ and } \prod_k b_k$$ could mean.

Comment: @user ... just like before, same question therefore same answer so I refer you to the answer I gave a few messages ago.  I still await your reference to exactly where "k" and "m" are defined.  Your absence of factual support for your claim they are clearly defined proves the weakness of your assertion.  But I have to say I just don't understand why you continue to deny the absence of definitions of "k" and "m" when it is clear in black and white by their omission.

Comment: I'm happy to hear more interesting and exciting value adding advice from you when you are able to give such that actually adds value rather than an unsupported claim to do so.  It's quite simple ... define "k" and "m" and this can move forward but I have yet to find a coding language that can resolve formulae without having the parameters defined.  I thought the intention of this website is to help questioners not frustrate them.

Comment: Thank you for very interesting input for the further discussion. But I still wait for the explanation (as complete as possible) of your understanding of the symbols $$\sum_i a_i,\quad \prod_k b_k.$$ Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Let ask $p(R_1>R_2)$.
It will be the sum of  all the $R_1$ values multiply by the chance its bigger then $R_2$.

$p(R_1>R_2) = \sum_{i \in [N_1]}\frac{1}{N_1}\cdot \frac{i-1}{N_2}=\frac{1}{N_1\cdot N_2}\cdot \sum_{i\in [N_1]}i-1=\frac{1}{N_1\cdot N_2}\cdot \frac{N_1^2-N_1}{2}=\frac{N_1-1}{2\cdot N_2}$

From here, $P(R_1 > R_2,R_3,...,R_n)=\frac{N_1-1}{2\cdot N_2}\cdot \frac{N_1-1}{2\cdot N_3}\cdot ...\cdot \frac{N_1-1}{2\cdot N_n}$

Comment: Thanks Shaq but I'm missing something.  :(  I think you are saying the prob. $R_1$ is the largest is $\frac{(N_1-1)}{2\cdot  N_2}\cdot  \frac{(N_1-1)}{2\cdot  N_3}$?  And $R_2$ is $\frac{(N_2-1)}{2\cdot  N_3}\cdot  \frac{(N_2-1)}{2\cdot  N_1}$?  And so on.  So the formula can be simplified to $$\frac{\frac{N_1-1}{2}^{(n-1)}}{N_2\cdot N_3 \cdot ... N_n}$$
But that gives the values for $P_1$, $P_2$  and  $P_3$ as 0.198669, 0.114817 and 0.672003 (sum= 0.985489) respectively which differs from my MCS and other inputs so I've probably misread your formula.  Sorry.   Where have I gone wrong?  :(